# Supporting the new Android plugins APIs

Tags: android, flutter

I'm working with flutter and I'm getting this error while I was trying to add lutter_bluetooth_serial to the pubspec.yaml. This is the error that I get.-->"The plugin `flutter_bluetooth_serial` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: [https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration."](https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.%22)
---->I don't know how to solve this issue Can you help???

Answer (score 0):

try this, add this line `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`

Run → Edit Configurations → Add Additional Run args → --no-sound-null-safety

[image]

Comment: ı add this to the configs but ı still have same error

Comment: okay check pubspec.yaml update all libraries and if any lib deprecated use alternative other lib.

Comment: how do ı update all libraries in pubspec.yaml

Comment: check one by one, and  deprecated lib you know that  so choose alternative.

Comment: ok but from where? I couldn't find it

Comment: edit here pubspec.yaml and check alternative lib here https://pub.dev/

Comment: It isn't working :/